# Why is TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy releasing messages in a minute even after setting timout to 15 minutes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have defined aggregator as below with release strategy as TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy. In this strategy, i have set timeout to 15 minutes and threshold to 10000. When the messages are released in 1 minute, which the default timeout of TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy. Please advise what could be missing

Spring version used is 5.3.25

```
 <int:aggregator 
      output-channel="messageOutFileChannel"
      send-partial-result-on-expiry="true"
      message-store="customMessageStore"
      correlation-strategy-expression="headers['fileName']
      ref="messageAggregatorService"
      method="aggregateMessages"
      release-strategy-expression="timeoutReleaseStrategy"    
      expire-groups-upon-completion="true"
      expire-groups-upon-timeout="true"
      id="customAggregator"
      input-channel="aggregatorInChannel" id="messageAggregator" >
</int:aggregator>

<bean id="customMessageStore"  class="org....SimpleMessageStore"/>
<bean id="timeoutReleaseStrategy" class="org....TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy">
   <constructor-arg name="threshold" value="10000"/>
      <constructor-arg name="timeout" value="900000"/> // 15 minutes
</bean>
```

Comment: You probably have a `MessageGroupStoreReaper`. Otherwise I cannot explain the reason to use those `send-partial-result-on-expiry` and `expire-groups-upon-timeout`. The timeout action in the `TimeoutCountSequenceSizeReleaseStrategy` happens only when message is sent to the aggregator anyway.

Comment: Would you mind shaping an answer for that then, please? It is not clear what and how helped you. I just made a couple assumptions, but I don't feel confident that it answers your problem.